# Can we use same hostname and domain in different spaces in Pivotal Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Our organization has many public facing web portals that are getting migrated to PCF. As part of this there are multiple teams that are structured under a single org that work for applications that are hosted under the same DNS domain, for example `test.domain.com`.

Now, suppose we have two teams that develop and deploy code in Space1 and Space2 under Org1. Both of these teams need to host their application under `test.domain.com`. The problem we are facing is if `test.domain.com` is created as a shared domain in PCF Space 1, the same combination is not allowed on Space2. Host cannot be same across spaces. So now we need to append a unique host for every route we need to create in different space.

- Space1: `app1-test.domain.com/app1-path/abc`
- Space2: `app2-test.domain.com/app2-path/xyz`

What I wished was allowed is:

- Space1: `test.domain.com/app1-path/abc`
- Space2: `test.domain.com/app2-path/xyz`

Is there any way to achive this behaviour within PCF?

Comment: If the two teams need to use the same host, and that can't be shared between spaces, why don't they use the same space?

Comment: Yes if that was possible there would have been no issues. But due to the organizational and team structures that is not possible. Same host (DNS domain ) also spans across different orgs within PCF and also needs to be shared across spaces. So I was looking for some help if there is a way to accomplish this within PCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work, but only if your domain is a private domain. If your administrator has created a shared domain then you won't be allowed to do this.

Ex:

```
$ cf create-domain dmikusa test.example.com
Creating domain test.example.com for org dmikusa as dmikusa@pivotal.io...
OK

$ cf domains
Getting domains in org dmikusa as dmikusa@pivotal.io...
name                 status   type   details
cfapps.io            shared
cf-tcpapps.io        shared   tcp
apps.internal        shared          internal
test.example.com     owned

$ cf create-route team-1 test.example.com --path foo
Creating route test.example.com/foo for org dmikusa / space team-1 as dmikusa@pivotal.io...
Route test.example.com/foo has been created.
OK

$ cf create-route team-2 test.example.com --path bar
Creating route test.example.com/bar for org dmikusa / space team-2 as dmikusa@pivotal.io...
Route test.example.com/bar has been created.
OK
```

If you were to try the same thing with a shared domain it would fail.

```
$ cf create-route team-1 cfapps.io --hostname my-super-cool-app --path foo
Creating route my-super-cool-app.cfapps.io/foo for org dmikusa / space team-1 as dmikusa@pivotal.io...
Route my-super-cool-app.cfapps.io/foo has been created.
OK

$ cf create-route team-2 cfapps.io --hostname my-super-cool-app --path foo
Creating route my-super-cool-app.cfapps.io/foo for org dmikusa / space team-2 as dmikusa@pivotal.io...
The path is taken: /foo
FAILED
```

There's a footnote in the docs about this at [the bottom of this section](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#create-route):

> Note: Routes with the same domain and hostname but different paths can only be created in the same space. Private domains do not have this limitation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel it absolutely helps. We will work with our PAAS admin team to test it out and see how we can use this for our use cases.